# Classifying groups of order 42 containing $S_3$ as a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I am attempting to classify groups of order $42$ which contain $S_3$ as a subgroup. I want to make sure what I am doing makes sense and maybe hear if there is a better way to do it, since my answer isn't what I hoped for.

My work: By the Sylow theorems, the Sylow $7$ subgroup, call it $\mathbb{Z}$ is normal. If we have $S_3$ in there, by relative primality and normality of $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}S_3\leq G_{42}$, we have that 
$$
G=P_7S_3\cong \mathbb{Z}_7\rtimes_{\phi}S_3
$$ 
where $\phi:S_3\to \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_7)=\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Writing $S_3=D_{6}=\langle x,y :x^2=1,y^3=1,xyx^{-1}=y^{-1}\rangle$
then we need to check wher we can send the generators $x,y$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

$x$ must be sent to something of order $1$ or $2$ and $y$ to something of order $1$ or $3$, leaving us with 
$$
\phi:x\mapsto 1,2\\
y\mapsto1,3
$$
where I ignored $x\mapsto 4$ since this generates the same subgroup as $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

If $x\mapsto 1$, and we want to avoid just the direct product we need 
$$
y\mapsto 3
$$
which corresponds to the automorphism on $\mathbb{Z}_7$ 
$$
z\mapsto z^{-1}
$$
yielding the group presentation
$$
\langle x,y,z:z^7=x^2=y^3=1,xyx^{-1}=y^{-1},xzx^{-1}=z, yzy^{-1}=z^{-1}\rangle
$$
If instead $x\mapsto 2$ corresponding to the automorphism 
$$
z\mapsto ((z^5)^2)z=z^{11}=z^4
$$
and $y\mapsto 3$ still, we have 
$$
\langle x,y,z:z^7=x^2=y^3=1,xyx^{-1}=y^{-1},xzx^{-1}=z^4, yzy^{-1}=z^{-1}\rangle
$$
finally if $x\mapsto 2$ and $y\mapsto 1$ we have 
$$
\langle x,y,z:z^7=x^2=y^3=1,xyx^{-1}=y^{-1},xzx^{-1}=z^4, yzy^{-1}=z \rangle
$$
and the group corresponding to both $y$ and $x$ mapping to the trivial automorphism
$$
\mathbb{Z}_7\times S_3
$$

Do these look ok? Is there a better way to tackle the problem?

Also, even if right, this isn't all that satisfying, is there a nicer way to write some of these group presentations? Like in some, two of the generators commute which feels like there should be a sort of direct product lurking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for homomorphisms $\phi:S_3\to\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_7)$.
Note that $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_7)$ is Abelian. If one has a group homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$ with $H$ Abelian, then $\phi$ is trivial
on the derived subgroup $[G,G]$ of $G$, and so factors through the
quotient group $G/[G,G]$. Here $G=S_3$, $[G,G]=A_3$
and $G/[G,G]\cong\Bbb Z_2$. So there are two possible $\phi$: the trivial
map $\phi_0$, and $\phi_1$ which sends even elements of $S_3$ to the
identity and odd elements to $z\mapsto -z$.

The map $\phi_0$ defines the direct product
$S_3\times\Bbb Z_7$. As $\phi_1$ is trivial
on $A_3$, your group $G_{42}$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to
$A_3\times \Bbb Z_7\cong \Bbb Z_{21}$. On an element $\tau$
of order two in $S_3$, $\phi$ acts as $-1$. So $\phi$ acts by negation
on $A_3\times \Bbb Z_7$ which means that $G_{42}$ is a dihedral group
of order $42$.